# PostgreSQL: 42883 Operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone = text

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, petapoco

I am using Npgsql 3.0.3.0 and PetaPoco latest version.

When I run this command:

```
var dateCreated = DateTime.Now; // just an example
var sql = new Sql("WHERE date_created = @0", dateCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00"));
var category = db.SingleOrDefault<Category>(sql);
```

I get the following error:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException 42883: operator does not exist: timestamp
>   without time zone = text

I understand the error message is saying I'm trying to compare a timestamp (date) with a text, however for me it's perfectly valid to compare them as I am *expecting* the following SQL statement to be built:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE date_created = '2017-02-03 15:00:00'
```

I don't really want to typecast my database column to text for performance reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to cast value to timestsamp:

```
var sql = new Sql("WHERE date_created = @0::timestamp", dateCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicit typecast text to timestamp.

Try using :

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(date_string,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: This one helped me big when using Postgres as the data source for SSRS reports with parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @roman-tkachuk answered, you can tell PostgreSQL to cast your string into a timestamp.

Or better yet, you can simply send a timestamp to PostgreSQL directly, rather than sending a string representation of a timestamp and having it cast. To do that, simply send `dateCreated` directly, without the `ToString()`.

Comment: Reason why I'm formatting the datetime with `ToString()` is that I need to ignore minutes and seconds.

Comment: You can do that just as well by creating a DateTime in C# with the minutes and seconds zeroed out. That's effectively what you're doing, just via a string, which is a less "tight". Definitely not very important - just mentioning it.